# SATA power connection on motherboard seems to be a 6-pin male. What kind of connector is this?

Tags: sata, power, cable, computer-building, connector

I have an HP PC that is missing the power cable for the HDD. It seems that the SATA power port on the motherboard is a straight 6 pin male connection as shown below:

[image: Motherboard 6-pin SATA power port]

What is the name of the connector/cable that plugs in to that? Is that proprietary?

The PC is an HP Slimline 260-a010.

Here's the whole inside and motherboard for reference:

[image: MOBO]

Comment: " Is that proprietary?" Yes

Comment: Punch in your Serial number at this link, it will list all the parts for that specific model, either order it from HP or search the internet using the HP part number.>>>>>>>https://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx

Comment: *"Is that proprietary?"* -- It's a industry-standard connector, but unusual to see for a PC power source.  Fan connections would be the closest example.   So it is simply not standard for storage drive power, but that does not make it proprietary.  Obviously they cannot use a SATA-style power connector for the source-end.  A standard Molex-style power connector probably uses too much board area.

Comment: @Moab - Thanks! I found part number 857341-002, which I believe is this: http://shop.ftgparts.com/Store/SATA-CABLES/857341-002.html - I see the connector that goes from the mobo to the HDD power connector, but why is there also a SATA data connector on the same wire harness? Why would data even be involved?

Comment: @sawdust - I guess I meant "Is the [cable/method of using this connector for SATA power] proprietary?" I feel like it would be easier for me to just chop up an existing cable vs buying one online for some ridiculous price and having to wait. But I'm not sure of the pinout.

Comment: @Bort Since it is proprietary it does both power and data, they can be found on eBay also.

Comment: @Moab - But there is already a data cable going from the HDD to the "HDD1" port on the mobo (See the 2nd photo). Do you think that doesn't belong?

Comment: Then just connect the power.